# Retrieving values from fckeditor in code behind in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, fckeditor

i am using fckeditor in my page in the code behind file i want to retrieve the value of fckeditor what i am doing is

```
FckEditor objFckEditor = new FckEditor();
string abcd = server.Htmlencode(objFckEditor.value.trim());
```

i have also imported 
using FredCK.FCKeditorV2; in the top

but it is returning only null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using the FCK server controls. In that case you do it in the same way as with any other server control (ex a textbox).

```
var abcd = [[nameOfEditor]].Value;
```

What you do is create a new instance of the FckEditor class. Then on the next line (without setting any values) you expect it to have its value property set. There is nothing special about this server control, it works in the same way as any other control.